# Log user browser id on each visit in python tornado

Tags: python, post, tornado

I have a JS, html and CSS pair working well and provide the user with an interactive webpage. I can use python -m SimpleHTTPServer to serve them and that was great. Now, I want to measure the number of users to my site. For this, I assumed I'd need some server code. So, I turned to python Tornado. I'm confused as to which HTTP protocol I should use to send this. Most boilerplate code has GET and POST methods implemented like so:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

def get(self):

    self.render("index.html")

#
# HTTP *POST* HANDLER
#
def post(self):
    print "Post received"
    post_body = self.get_argument("body")
    if post_body:
        print "post body : %s..." % post_body[0:400]
```

And I understand that tornado has asynchronous versions of these we well. Which of them is best suited to indicate to the server that a user with a certain browser cookie has accessed the page? If the answer were GET, how would I distinguish that request from the GET request that loads up the page for the first time?

Also, is there anything better than a unique browser cookie to distinguish a user that doesn't involve them creating an account?

Answer (score 1):

To navigate to site from location bar/link browsers use GET. You can distinguish visit by detecting [cookie in RequestHandler](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#cookies):

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        if self.get_cookie('visited'):
            # this is not first visit
            print('not first visit')
        else:
            self.set_cookie('visited', '1'):
            # first visit
            print('for the first time')
        self.render("index.html")
```

The cookie seems to be the right way. Of course user can modify/remove cookie. Others approaches like ip + user_agent based identification, has a drawbacks as well - fails on shared ip.

And finally, if you plan a simple counter for home page, go and play implementing it by yourself. But if not, the real feature-full solutions, that solve the same problems as yours (and other you will be facing), is to used appropriate tool - take a look at [piwik](http://piwik.org/) (open source) or Google Analytics, clicky...